# Azure Front Door Custom Domain Https Stuck in PendingDomainControlValidationRequestApproval state

Tags: azure-front-door

I enabled the Custom Domain Https for a frontend/domain in my Azure Front Door and also made sure that the CNAME in the DNS points to the correct value. Now The process is stuck in the PendingDomainControlValidationRequestApproval (Domain validation) step since 7 hours.

For another Domain, the verification almost happened immediately.

Now i would like to disable the Custom Domain Https to use my own certificate but when i try to disable Custom Domain Https, Azure errors with the message "The requested operation cannot be executed on the entity in the current state."

Is there a possibility to abort the Domain validation step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into this issue as well and it happens when you switch from "Azure managed" to "Use my own certificate". Unfortunately the only way we were able to get around it was to delete the custom entry from front door, save it, and add it again. Have the certificate ready in the KeyVault before you do it so that you can select "Use my own certificate" right away while you're creating it.